# Как найти и добавить определенный символ в string?

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, есть строка

```
string str="go hi . uyyuer";
```

Как можно в этой строке найти символ, допустим `"."`, а потом скопировать его?

В результате, чтобы получилось такое:

```
str="go hi .. uyyuer";
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str.insert (str.find("."), ".");
```

P.S. Общий вариант:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length()-1; i++)
    if (str.at(i) == '.') str.insert (i++, ".");
```

Можно через STL как-то попробовать.

Comment: Вообщем-то верно, а если таких точек много? то как быть?

Comment: Добавил общий вариант

Comment: почему-то он добавляет к 1-у..., получается такое text....  ...texr

Comment: Спасибо!!! Я сам ошибся сперва...